# Quick ModRewrite and GET question

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I'm trying to return a success notice if the $_GET['success'] is set. It works fine if I input it like this: mail?inbox&success

But I'm trying to make it work if I input it like this: mail/inbox/success or mail/inbox&success

I'm not very experienced with mod_rewrite and I havent found a solution yet so I'm asking here. How would I get it to work with the examples above? This is what the .htaccess looks like right now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /userinfo?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^items/([^/]*)$ /items?weapon=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^mail/inbox /mail?inbox [L]
RewriteRule mail/(.*)/(.*)$ /mail?read=$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change

```
RewriteRule ^mail/inbox/ /mail?inbox [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^mail/inbox/(.*) /mail?inbox&$1 [L]
```

Depends on what other combinations you want to rewrite.
Adding the line

```
RewriteRule ^mail/inbox/success /mail?inbox&success [L]
```

before the first rule should do it also, but only for this one case and may influence other rules.

Comment: That turns to /mail?inbox. I want it to be /mail/inbox/

Comment: it matches /mail/inbox/success and passes it as /mail?inbox&success as you asked for

Comment: Nevermind, If I add another slash it works but if I put in /mail/inbox/success it doesnt do anything. How is it supposed to be used?

Comment: if there is another matching rule before with an [L], this one was the last and the rest is skipped. maybe thats the problem then...

Comment: Got it to work with "RewriteRule ^mail/inbox/success /mail?inbox&success [L]" Thanks for your help :)